# Laravel leftJoin only last record of right table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am new to laravel.

I have two tables.
1) products
2) prices

```
-----------------------------
- products                  -
-----------------------------
- id_product | int (p_key)  -
- name       | varchar      -
-----------------------------

-------------------------
- prices                -
-----------------------------
- id_price   | int (p_key)  -
- id_product | int          -
- price      | int          -
-----------------------------
```

the `products` table holds data about products like `id`, `name`,...
the price changes are stored in `prices` table where the last record is the newest price that should be displayed to users.

now I want to search through `products` and get the last price of each product from `prices` table. this is my query:

```
$result = DB::table('products')->leftJoin('prices', function($join) {
    $join->on('products.id_product', '=', 'prices.id_product');
})->whereRaw(MY_SEARCH_FILTERS);
```

the above code is wrong because if a product has 4 records in `prices` table, then it will be repeated 4 times in `$result`, but only 1 record with the last price should be displayed.

Answer (score 16):

Here we have 2 tables **users** and **answers** where **users** is left table and **answers** is right table which has user answers.

We wanted to left join **users** with **answers** but the join should be with the latest record or **answers** table.

```
$query = Users::select('users.id', 'users.user_name','answers.created_at as last_activity_date')
->leftJoin('answers', function($query) 
{
   $query->on('users.id','=','answers.user_id')
   ->whereRaw('answers.id IN (select MAX(a2.id) from answers as a2 join users as u2 on u2.id = a2.user_id group by u2.id)');
})
->where('users.role_type_id', Users::STUDENT_ROLE_TYPE)->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

you can make make it easy by using Laravel Elquent:

```
class Product extends Model
{
   public function lastPrice()
    {
        // optional: change id_price  to created_at by add created_at to prices table 
        return $this->hasOne(Price::class)->orderBy('id_price', 'DESC');
    }

}
```

now in

```
public function getProducts(){
 $MY_SEARCH_FILTERS=....;
 // get all products with last price 
 $products=Product::with('lastPrice')->whereRaw(MY_SEARCH_FILTERS)->get()  
 return   $products
}
```

Comment: This query is not performant due to amount loaded models and size of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here we have 2 tables '**`articles`**' and '**`comments`**' where **`articles`** is left table and **`comments`** is right table which has article's comments.

We wanted to left join **`articles`** with **`comments`** but the join should be with the latest record from **`comments`** table.

```
$query = Article::select('articles.*', 'comments.comment as article_comment')
->leftJoin('comments', function($query) {
    $query->on('comments.article_id','=','articles.id')
        ->whereRaw('comments.id IN (select MAX(a2.id) from comments as a2 join articles as u2 on u2.id = a2.article_id group by u2.id)');
})
->get();
```

i found this solution from here https://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-get-last-record-from-leftjoin-table-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two things in here,

> 1) orderBy descending on prices table.
>
> 2) first clause in the DB::table function (It will fetch only 1
>   record, that will be the latest price).

**The solution :**

```
$result = DB::table('products')
->leftJoin('prices',function($join)
                    {
                      $join->on('products.id_product', '=',  'prices.id_product')
                    })->whereRaw(MY_SEARCH_FILTERS)
->orderBy('prices.id_price','desc')
->first();
```

**You can also use (Laravel 5.1) :**

```
$result = DB::table('products')
          ->leftJoin('products.id','=','prices.id_product')
          ->whereRaw(MY_SEARCH_FILTERS)
          ->orderBy('prices.id_price','desc')
          ->first();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I think that I did not explained the issue correctly. there may be 100 records in `products` table. I want all of them to be left-joined with their last price from`prices` table and be fetched with the query.

Comment: @Agha Ok, then use group by and ->get instead of ->first. This should do the job.